# Blender texture baking?? Can we bake blender cycle material into texture with bump included

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

Blender texture baking?? Can we bake blender cycle material into texture with bump included....
Or Anybody please explain how to export from blender(cycles) to unity with material

Comment: Google "how to bake normals blender" or "texture from blender to unity". Basically, try to research if someone else has already answered the question before asking it on this platform. Sorry I don't mean to be rude but this specially true when new to a software as there is a good chance someone has already faced the same problem and avoids duplicated questions...